# TABLOCK for both truncate and subsequent bulk insert

Tags: sql-server

I'd like to truncate a table and then run a bulk insert on it with some new data.

I tried a query something like this:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION; 

TRUNCATE TABLE db.dbo.table;

BULK INSERT db.dbo.table 
FROM 'file.txt'
WITH (TABLOCK, FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0a');

COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

However it seems like I can query a time between the truncate and the insert. Granted this is a small time window but I would like to eliminate it entirely.

How can I edit the query so the TABLOCK (or better TABLOCKX?) locks the table from when the truncate begins to when the bulk insert ends?

Answer (score 1):

> However it seems like I can query a time between the truncate and the insert. Granted this is a small time window but I would like to eliminate it entirely.

No, there is no opportunity to do anything with the table after the truncate. `TRUNCATE TABLE` takes a schema-modification (Sch-M) lock, which is the most restrictive lock available – more so even than an exclusive table lock. The Sch-M lock is held until the end of the transaction.

Sch-M [conflicts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-transaction-locking-and-row-versioning-guide#lock_compatibility) with every other type of lock (except the null lock), including the schema-stability (Sch-S) lock taken for reads under `READ UNCOMMITTED` and the row-versioning isolation levels:

[image: Lock compatibility matrix]

Conceptually, an Sch-M lock indicates that the very structure of the table is changing, so it is not safe for anything else to touch it until the operation is committed or rolled back. (Truncating a table doesn't actually change the visible structure from a user's point of view, but pages and extents are deallocated in bulk.)

You can test this by running the truncate statement inside a transaction, then trying to read or insert data on a separate connection. Whatever you try will be blocked until the transaction containing the truncate is resolved.

There is therefore no need to do what you are asking.

Answer (score -2):

The table lock is not taken until a statement containing that hint is executed. Since TRUNCATE cannot be hinted we must add another statement that can be. A SELECT will suffice. We want it to be fast so a restrictive predicate is good. Something like

```
begin transaction;

select primary_key
from dbo.table (tablockx)
where 1=2;

.. etc.
```

It would be nice if we could use sp_getapplock for this but it cannot, at the time of writing, address schema objects.

Comment: `TRUNCATE` will acquire a restrictive `Sch-M` lock until committed so I don't think the additional `SELECT` is needed.

Comment: So the idea is that `select` is just a dummy query to engage the tablockx? Is there something more general I could use like `select top 1 * from dbo.table (tablockx)`.. ? I have some tables that don't have primary keys

Comment: @R.M. doesn't matter - that select statement does nothing (selects no rows) and exists only to acquire the lock. But as Dan wrote - it probably isn't needed. This is starting to sound like premature optimization.

Comment: @SMor exactly. The column list is unimportant, only the table reference and the hint matter.

Comment: @MichaelGreen And I made no reference to the column list - so that comment is not understood. "Some data manipulation language (DML) operations, such as table truncation, use Sch-M locks to prevent access to affected tables by concurrent operations." [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-transaction-locking-and-row-versioning-guide?view=sql-server-ver15)